# find: paths must precede expression

Tags: linux, find

I ran this command:

```
find /home/ ~ -type f -size 5 "*." -a -30
```

but it said `find: paths must precede expression`. 
I am having a hard time getting `find` to look for matches in the current directory as well as its subdirectories. 
What does this error mean, and how can I get the matches from both the current directory and its subdirectories?

Answer (score 6):

As you seem to understand,
you can specify multiple starting points for `find`; e.g.,

```
find  dir1  dir2  dir3  -type f  … (other arguments) …
```

But your `"*."` and `-30` are not valid search/action terms,
so `find` thinks you're providing more starting points after the `-type f`. 
Perhaps you mean `-name "*."` and `-mtime -30`?

P.S. `-name "*."` would match all names that end with a period (**`.`**),
a.k.a. dot or full stop. 
While valid, that would be a fairly unusual pattern;
is it really what you mean?

P.P.S. If your home directory (represented by `~`) is under `/home`,
then your command is redundant, as it will search your home directory twice.